# AWS-CDK: Cross account Resource Access and Resource reference

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-kms

I have a secret key-value pair in `Secrets Manager` in Account-1 in `us-east-1`. This secret is encrypted using a Customer managed KMS key - let's call it `KMS-Account-1`. All this has been created via console.

Now we turn to `CDK`. We have `cdk.pipelines.CodePipeline` which deploys `Lambda` to multiple stages/environments - so 1st to `{ Account-2, us-east-1 }` then to `{ Account-3, eu-west-1` } and so on. This has been done.

The lambda code in all stages/environments above, now needs to be changed to use the secret key-value pair present with Account-1's `us-east-1` `SecretsManager` by getting it via `secretsmanager` client. That code should probably look like this (`python`):

```py
client = boto3.session.Session().client(
    service_name = 'secretsmanager',
    region_name = 'us-east-1'
)
resp = client.get_secret_value(
    SecretId='arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:<ACCOUNT-1>:secret:name/of/the/secret'
)
secret = json.loads(resp['SecretString'])
```

All lambdas in various accounts and regions (ie. environments) will have the exact same code as above since the secret needs to be fetched from Account-1 in `us-east-1`.

1. Firstly I hope this is conceptually possible. Is that right?
2. Next how do I change the `cdk` code to facilitate this? How will the code-deploy in code-pipeline get permission to import this custom `kms` key and `SecretManager' secret`and apply correct permissions for cross account access by the lambdas that the cdk pipeline creates ?

Can someone please give some pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is bit tricky as CloudFormation, and hence CDK, doesn't allow cross account/cross stage references because CloudFormation export doesn't work cross account as far as my understanding goes. All these patterns of "centralised" resources fall into that category - ie. resource in one account (or a stage in CDK) referenced by other stages.

If the resource is created outside the context of CDK (like via console), then you might as well hardcode the names/arns/etc. throughout the CDK code where its used and that should be sufficient.

1. For resources that have the ability to hold resource based policies, it's simpler as you can just attach the cross-account access permissions to them directly - again, offline via console since you are maintaining it manually anyway. Each time you add a stage (account) to your pipeline, you will need to go to the resource and add cross-account permissions manually.
2. For resources that don't have resource based policies, like SSM for eg., things are a bit roundabout as you will need to create a Role that can be assumed cross-account and then access the resource. In that case you will have to separately maintain the IAM Role too and manually update the trust policy to other accounts as you add stages to your CDK pipeline. Then, as usual hardcode the role arn in your CDK code, assume it in some CustomResource lambda and use it.

It gets more interesting if the creation is also done in the CDK code itself (ie. managed by CloudFormation - not done separately via console/aws-cli etc.). In this case, many times you wouldn't "know" the exact ARNs as the physical-id would be generated by CloudFormation and likely be a part of the ARN. Even influencing the physical-id yourself (like by hardcoding the bucket name) might not solve it in all cases. Eg. `KMS ARNs` and `SecretManager ARNs` append unique-ids or some sort of hashes to the end of the `ARN`.

Instead of trying to work all that out, it would be best left untouched and let `CFn` generate whatever random name/arn it chooses. To then reference these constructs/ARNs, just put them into SSM Parameters in the source/central account. SSM doesn't have resource based policy that I know of. So additionally create a role in cdk that trusts the accounts in your cdk code. Once done, there is no more maintenance - each time you add new environments/accounts to CDK (assuming its a cdk pipeline here), the "loop" construct that you will create will automatically add the new account into the trust relationship.

Now all you need to do is to distribute this role-arn and the SSM Parameternames to other stages. Choose an explicit role-name and SSM Parameters. The manual ARN construction given a rolename is pretty straightforward. So distribute that and SSM Parameters around your CDK code to other stages (compile time strings instead of references). In target stages, create  custom-resource(s) (`AWSCustomResource`) backed by `AwsSdkCall` lambda to simply assume this role-arn and make the SDK call to retrieve the SSM Parameter values. These values can be anything, like your KMS ARNs, SecretManager's full ARNs etc. which you couldn't easily guess. Now simply use these.

Roundabout way to do a simple thing, but so far that is all I could do to get this to work.

```
#You need to maintain this list no matter what you do - so it's nothing extra
all_other_accounts = [ <list of accounts that this cdk deploys to> ]

account_principals = [iam.AccountPrincipal(a) for a in all_other_account]
role = iam.Role(
   assumed_by = iam.CompositePrincipal(*account_principals), #auto-updated as you change the list above
   role_name = some_explicit_name,
   ...
)
role_arn = f'arn:aws:iam::<account-of-this-stack>:role/{some_explicit_name}'

kms0 = kms.Key(...)
kms0.grant_decrypt(role)
# Because KMS also needs explicit resource policy even if role policy allows access to it
kms0.add_to_role_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(principals = [iam.ArnPrincipal(role_arn)], actions = ...))

kms1 = kms.Key(...)
kms1.grant_decrypt(role)
kms0.add_to_role_policy(... same as above ...)

secrets0 = secretsmanager.Secret(...) #maybe this is based off kms0
secrets0.grant_read(role)
secrets1 = secretsmanager.Secret(...) #maybe this is based off kms1
secrets1.grant_read(role)

# You can turn all this into a loop ofc.
ssm0 = ssm.StingParameter(self, '...', parameter_name = 'kms0_arn', string_value = kms0.key_arn, ...)
ssm0.grant_read(role)
ssm1 = ssm.StingParameter(self, '...', parameter_name = 'kms1_arn', string_value = kms1.key_arn, ...)
ssm1.grant_read(role)
ssm2 = ssm.StingParameter(self, '...', parameter_name = 'secrets0_arn', string_value = secrets0.secret_full_arn, ...)
ssm2.grant_read(role)
...

#Now simply pass around the role and ssm parameter names
for env in environments:
   MyApplicationStage(self, <...>, ..., role_arn = role_arn, params = [ 'kms0_arn', 'kms1_arn', ... ], ...)
```

And then in the target stage(s):

```
for parm in params:
   fn = AwsSdkCall('ssm', 'get_parameter', { "Name": param }, ...)
   acr = AwsCustomResource(..., on_create = fn, on_update = fn, ...)
   collect['param'] = acr.get_response_field('Parameter.Value')
```

Now do whatever you want with the collected artifacts, including supplying them as environment variables to your main service lambda (which will be resolved at deploy time).

Remember they will all be Tokens and resolved only at deploy time, but that's true of any resource, whether or not via custom-resource and it shouldn't matter.

That's a generic pattern which should work for any case.

([GitHub link where this question was asked and I had answered it there too](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/17341#issuecomment-963344419))

Comment: This answer may need to be updated now that "stack sets" exist.